# How do I check for duplicates in a List<Model>

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, group-by

I have a model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int GridX { get; set; }
    public int GridY { get; set; }
}
```

The user will upload a list from an excel sheet that will look something like:

```
GridX       GridY
  1           3
  1           2
  1           4
  2           2
  2           1
  2           1
```

I currently upload the excel sheet, and loop through the rows to create a List which I will then save to the db.

I have to be able to catch duplicate rows, like the the last 2 rows that have the same coordinates (2,1).

I know for a single list I can do something like:

```
  var hasDuplicates = MyList.GroupBy(x => x.num).Any(x => x.Count() > 1);
```

and hasDuplicate will be true if there are duplicates in the list.  I am not sure how to do this in the case of having pairs that need to be compared.  Each set of coordinates should be a group but not sure how to groupby a set.  I could do it in sql, but alas I have to catch it before it gets to the db.

Comment: You can overwrite **MyModel.Equals** method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how - you can group by *both* properties by creating an anonymous type within the `GroupBy`:

```
MyList.GroupBy(x => new { GridX = x.GridX, GridY = x.GridY }).Any(x => x.Count() > 1);
```

Comment: Good thought, but that actually won't work unless the logical duplicates are actually references to the *same* object - they almost certainly will not be references to the same object in OP's case. You could theoretically build an `IEqualityComparer` and pass that into the `Distinct` call (one of the overrides) to specify that a `MyModel` is equal to another if the two columns are identical, but that's too much work when this `GroupBy` option is available.

Comment: This did the trick, though I did have to modify it slightly. This version ran but returned incorrect result.  I removed the assigning in the group and that worked:  MyList.GroupBy(x => new { x.GridX, x.GridY }).Any(x => x.Count() > 1);  If anyone can tell me the difference, I am very interested to know.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Aother solution is implement MyModelComparer and use Distinct

```
class MyModelComparer : IEqualityComparer<MyModel>
{
    public bool Equals(MyModel x, MyModel y)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        return x.GridX == y.GridX && x.GridY == y.GridY;
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects 
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects.

    public int GetHashCode(MyModel model)
    {
        return (model.GridX.GetHashCode()*397)^model.GridY.GetHashCode
    }

}
```

And after that use Distinct `var result = MyList.Distinct(new MyModelComparer());`

Comment: In the GetHashCode, you missed `product` for GridX and GridY.